# SQL Query logic for order by

Tags: sql, .net, sql-server, t-sql, logic

I am facing issues for creating a order by logic in SQL query:

Query is shown below:

```
WITH CTE AS ( SELECT CommentID ,
                CommentUserName,
                 ReplyCommentID ,
                CommentID AS ThreadID ,
                CAST( CommentID AS VARCHAR( MAX ) ) AS PathStr,
                HtmlComment ,
                CommentPostDocumentID ,
                 CommentIsApproved,
                CommentDate 

         FROM Blog_CommentDetails AS T WITH(NOLOCK)
         WHERE ReplyCommentID IS NULL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT T.CommentID ,
                T.CommentUserName,
                T.ReplyCommentID ,
                CTE.ThreadID ,
                PathStr + '-'+ CAST( T.ReplyCommentID AS VARCHAR( MAX ) ) AS PathStr,
                T.HtmlComment ,
                t.CommentPostDocumentID ,
                 t.CommentIsApproved,
                T.CommentDate 

         FROM Blog_CommentDetails AS T WITH(NOLOCK)
         JOIN CTE 
         ON T.ReplyCommentID = CTE.CommentID
         WHERE T.ReplyCommentID IS NOT NULL)

SELECT *
    FROM CTE
    WHERE CommentPostDocumentID = 15 AND CommentIsApproved=1
    ORDER BY ThreadID, PathStr ,
            CommentDate DESC;
```

Its shows the following result:

[image: Query Result]

But the expected result is:
[image]

Change is , I need to insert the record just after commentid - 144 because reply commentid and commentid is same.

Means whenever there is a matching commentid and replycommentid , in this case its 144, then the row with replycommentid should come down to the row having the commentid 144.

Query listing for the answer:

[image: query result for DVT]

Comment: And what is the logic behind this new order?

Comment: order should remain same as per my initial query, plus need a insert if the replyid is matching, now the insert is happeing on last , existing order should not change it should remain intact

Comment: Try writing down what you want in words. Regarding the order of the output of a query, only those specified in the `ORDER BY` clause are guaranteed. Otherwise, if `SQL-Server` pick a different execution plan, you might get different order of the result, even for the same query.

Comment: Also, avoid the use of "insert", unless you are actually talking about `inserting`. Since you are selecting, not inserting,  it's confusing.

Answer (score 1):

How about sorting by the string of commentID of the parent record combination with current record

```
WITH CTE AS ( SELECT CommentID ,
                CommentUserName,
                 ReplyCommentID ,
                CommentID AS ThreadID ,
                CAST( CommentID AS VARCHAR( MAX ) ) AS PathStr,
                HtmlComment ,
                CommentPostDocumentID ,
                 CommentIsApproved,
                CommentDate ,
                CAST('' AS VARCHAR(MAX)) AS NewPathStr -- added
         FROM Blog_CommentDetails AS T WITH(NOLOCK)
         WHERE ReplyCommentID IS NULL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT T.CommentID ,
                T.CommentUserName,
                T.ReplyCommentID ,
                CTE.ThreadID ,
                PathStr + '-'+ CAST( T.ReplyCommentID AS VARCHAR( MAX ) ) AS PathStr,
                T.HtmlComment ,
                t.CommentPostDocumentID ,
                 t.CommentIsApproved,
                T.CommentDate,              
                CTE.NewPathStr+'--'+CAST(cte.CommentID AS VARCHAR(MAX)) + '-' + CAST(t.CommentID AS VARCHAR(MAX)) AS NewPathStr  --added
         FROM Blog_CommentDetails AS T WITH(NOLOCK)
         JOIN CTE 
         ON T.ReplyCommentID = CTE.CommentID
         WHERE T.ReplyCommentID IS NOT NULL)

SELECT *  -- You might have to remove NewpathStr if you do not want to see it
    FROM CTE
    WHERE CommentPostDocumentID = 15 AND CommentIsApproved=1
    ORDER BY ThreadID, NewPathStr, PathStr ,
            CommentDate DESC;
```

Comment: oops. Forgot that a null string and an empty string are different. @SmartestVEGA Fixed.

Comment: Now my requirement is listing fine , which is after the 144 its inserted the replycommentid 144, but the order of the query gone for a toss, the match two records are inserted in last and second last position, ideally it should be in the second and third position

Answer (score 0):

This is deep first approach and can be done using ORDER BY hierarchyid values thus:

(1)
ORDER BY
    ThreadId,
    CONVERT(HIERARCHYID, '\' + REPLACE(PathStr, '-', '\') + '\'),
    CommentDate

or

(2) Within recursive CTE I would generate PathStr as hirarchyid values.

Note: I didn't tested this solution.
Note #2: Sorry for bad formatting: I'm writting this answer on my phone.